# What does "void (* parse_arg_function)(const char*)" function argument mean in C?

Tags: c

What does the last function argument mean in C language?
Please, point to documentation where I can read about it.

```
void parse_options( int argc, char **argv, const OptionDef *options, 
                   void (* parse_arg_function)(const char*) )
```

Thanks.

Comment: This call is not from the standard library and you didn't provide us with any link about the frameworks you were using, so no once can point to documentation. However, people can post useful answers about what is a function pointer.

Comment: @zneak: google helped. Indeed, not a standard library method, but refer to my answer: it's part of ffmpeg.

Comment: The function is from FFMpeg library. But the question asked is not about the meaning of function in some framework, the question is about C language construction used as last argument. I mean a "C language documentation" not a framework function doc. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [pointer to a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) that takes a `const char*` and returns `void`.

For more information, see [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's a function pointer.  The function is called `parse_arg_function`, it accepts a `const char*` argument, and it returns `void`.

In the case you've shown, the function pointer is essentially being used as a callback.  Inside that function, it might be used along the lines of

```
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    parse_arg_function(argv[i]);
}
// ...
```

You might want to read over [this function pointer tutorial](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html) for a more in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) is a good introduction on function pointers. Think of them as the address of the code pertaining to a function in memory.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about what a declaration means in C, you can [ask cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+(*+parse_arg_function)(const+char*)):

> declare parse_arg_function as pointer to function (pointer to const char) returning void

Answer (score 1):

This is a function from the [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) library. Quote from the [online documentation](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/cmdutils_8c.html#1e1cd70de83229e9d469b4d63c6097d4) about ffmpeg:

> *parse_arg_function*   Name of the function called to process every argument without a leading option name flag. NULL if such arguments do not have to be processed.

In other words: when you want to do some processing yourself for each argument, you can give your own function. Otherwise, just use `NULL`.