# What's the meaning of these types and declarations in C?

Tags: c

```
int (*is_space)(unsigned char);
int (*is_term)(unsigned char);
size_t blk_size;
void *(*malloc_func)(size_t);
void *(*realloc_func)(void *, size_t);
```

I am not very clear about what these types and declarations refer to.

Can anyone help  me?

Comment: google "function pointer"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "void (\* parse\_arg\_function)(const char\*)" function argument mean in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574906/what-does-void-parse-arg-functionconst-char-function-argument-mean-in-c)

Comment: [How do you read C declarations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations)

Answer (score 2):

These are [function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).

For example, `is_space` is a pointer to a type of function which takes `unsigned char` as parameter and returns an `int`

These are useful to define [callback functions](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/02/function-pointers-and-callbacks-in-c-an-odyssey/).

Comment: `size_t blk_size` is not a function pointer; `size_t` is an alias for an integral type that "can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array). On many platforms (...) std::size_t can safely store the value of any non-member pointer, in which case it is synonymous with std::uintptr_t." (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)

Answer (score 0):

`int (*is_space)(unsigned char);` - pointer to `integer` function that accepts `unsigned

`char`int (*is_term)(unsigned char);` - the same

`void *(*malloc_func)(size_t);` and `void *(*realloc_func)(void *, size_t);` are pointers to `void*` functions.

See also [this](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)